# How does Eclipse know whether the Swing Designer is available for a JFrame-derived class?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, gwt

I am using Google Web Toolkit's Swing Designer in Eclipse to create and edit components like custom JFrame's.

The problem is that the Design View is sometimes broken for my class (probably because the project is also being edited by another person in a different platform), and I want to know how to restore it.  In other words, I am able to edit the code for a custom JFrame, but I cannot use the visual editor to modify the JFrame anymore.  I notice that the icon for my JFrame's source code also changes to a normal java-source-code icon when the design view is broken.

In which file does Eclipse keep track of what JFrame's can be edited using the visual editor and which ones not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to open a file in the designer, but that's not happening by default, then use right-click *Open With>WindowBuilder Editor*.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That fixes the issue, and Eclipse even remembers to use the WindowBuilder Editor the next time that the file is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the **Design** tab, that means that you are just using the standard Eclipse Java Editor rather than the WindowBuilder editor. Eclipse allows you to use different editors via the **Open With** command. This is very basic Eclipse behavior, so it is something you should learn about. This is also covered in the WB [**docs**](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/features/editing_existing_window.html) and [**FAQ**](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/faq.html#DesignTab).